# Message passing with chrome.downloads

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension. I have a content script and an event page. From the content script, I send a message using chrome.runtime.sendMessage() to the event page. On the event page, I use onMessage event listener to send back a reponse -- however, I would like to send this reponse AFTER chrome has detected that a file has started downloading.

contentScript.js

```
window.location.href = download_link; //redirecting to download a file    

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

eventPage.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function(DownloadItem downloadItem) {
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});

        return true;
    });

});
```

Now, I haven't tried chrome.downloads.onCreated listener before, but I'm assuming this is the correct syntax. However, the code is not working, and the console is returning this error:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://dlkbhmbjncfpnmfgmpbmdfjocjbflmbj/ytmp3.js:59:31
    at disconnectListener (extensions::messaging:335:9)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:395:22)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatchToListener] (extensions::utils:65:26)
    at EventImpl.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:378:35)
    at EventImpl.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:401:17)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatch] (extensions::utils:65:26)
```

I have tried this without the chrome.downloads.onCreated listener and it works, the response is fetched by the content script. I read online that you need to add **return true;** in order to make it work, but it's not working for me. I suspect it's because of the second event listener, which enters a new scope meaning that sendResponse cannot be called from there -- if that's the case, how do I call the sendResponse function?

Comment: Why are you defining the `chrome.downloads.onCreated` listener inside of the `chrome.runtime.onMessage` listener?

Comment: I don't know how else to use it -- I'm new to chrome extension event pages, so I'm not sure how to do this properly. How else can I call the chrome.download.onCreated from the content script when needed?

Answer (score 0):

You `return true;` from the wrong place.

The [purpose of that return](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) is to say "I have not called `sendResponse` yet, but I'm going to".

However, you are returning it from inside the `onCreated` callback - it is too late by then, as right after the listener is added your original `onMessage` handler terminates. You just have to move the line:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener( function(DownloadItem downloadItem) {
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    });
    return true;
});
```

Comment: just tried it, I still get the same error that says it cannot read the property 'farewell'.

Comment: Ah well, note that you're also initiating the download before registering a handler (and you probably don't want to register it on every download, instead registering it once)

Comment: Oh, thanks, didn't notice that. Still, I get the same error :( Do you know of another way to achieve this? I just want to know in my content script when a download has started.

Comment: That would be a different question, probably not well-suited for Stack  Overflow.

Comment: Finally got it to work! The problem was the event listener `onCreated`, as it doesn't seem to ever fire?? I tried `onDeterminingFilename` event listener instead, and it works like a charm :)